# How to add JVMOptions in a JavaFX bundle created on Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, virtual-keyboard

I'm trying to bundle a JavaFX application adding a JVMOption to able virtual keyboard in my software, adding the "VM options" in the "Run/Debug Configurations" form works perfect in a test context, but when I build a DMG bundle and then run the app the keyboard is not shown. When I inspect the package content directly from the Application folder I found that the file "Content/Java/project.cfg" doesn't have JVM options

```
[Application]
app.name=Project
app.mainjar=Project.jar
app.version=0.6.1
app.preferences.id=Project_id
app.mainclass=co/Main
app.classpath=
app.runtime=$APPDIR/PlugIns/Java.runtime
app.identifier=Project_id

[JVMOptions]

[JVMUserOptions]

[ArgOptions]
```

If I add the option manually and save the file, the application works well showing the virtual keyboard.

```
[Application]
app.name=Project
app.mainjar=Project.jar
app.version=0.6.1
app.preferences.id=Project_id
app.mainclass=co/Main
app.classpath=
app.runtime=$APPDIR/PlugIns/Java.runtime
app.identifier=Project_id

[JVMOptions]
-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true
-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true
-Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx

[JVMUserOptions]

[ArgOptions]
```

Does somebody know how to add these options without hacking any file? just adding it to a configuration file inside the project.

My project was created using Java 8, JavaFX, IntelliJ Idea CE (2019), Gradle 4.8

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your build.xml file:

```
<fx:platform basedir="${JAVA_HOME}">
  <fx:property name="com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded" value="true"/>
  <fx:property name="com.sun.javafx.touch" value="true"/>
  <fx:property name="com.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard" value="javafx"/>
</fx:platform>
```